# Installing phpredis on osx with pecl

Tags: makefile, phpredis

I have some trouble installing `phpredis` on my Mac OSX Maverics.

I do have `redis server` installed and running. I used `sudo pecl install redis` to install phpredis. 
Now when I was doing that, this what came up:

```
running: make
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootEsw0Wz/redis-2.2.4/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/redis -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootEsw0Wz/redis-2.2.4/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootEsw0Wz/redis-2.2.4/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/redis -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/redis/redis.c -o redis.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/redis -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootEsw0Wz/redis-2.2.4/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootEsw0Wz/redis-2.2.4/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/redis -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/redis/redis.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/redis.o
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/redis/redis.c:27:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/redis/common.h:1:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [redis.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

What's this all about? seams like make failed because of missing php.h file. But why is that and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your php is not available in environment variable path or installation is picking php from some default location.