# Installing redis with pecl

Tags: php, redis, pecl

I'm trying to install redis with pecl and finally got the error.

```
sudo pecl install redis 

In file included from /private/tmp/pear/install/redis/redis.c:27:
/private/tmp/pear/install/redis/common.h:1:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [redis.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I found the same question as mine

[Installing phpredis on osx with pecl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039989/installing-phpredis-on-osx-with-pecl)

Answer: Looks like your php is not available in environment variable path or installation is picking php from some default location.

How I can confirm if my php is not available in environment variable path or installation is picking php from some default location? Plus, please let me know if you know another way to make it.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old question but I had same error when tried to install rdkafa. I think you had php installed via brew.
Run the following command then try installing again.

`export PATH="$(brew --prefix php)/bin:$PATH"`